# How can I spool a csv formatted file using an SQL Command?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, command, spool

I have an SQL query that generates a result regarding the daily data from the database.  I want a csv formatted file to be generated everyday with this query and saved in a folder.  Is there any way I can do this?

NOTE: I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 with regards to the DB.

Comment: Without knowing the DB it's a bit hard to guess. ;)

Comment: @Devolus it is an SQL Database

Comment: I guesses that it is an SQL Database from your title. ;) At least we know now that its MS SQLServer.

Comment: @Devolus that is correct.

Comment: @omar K - Are you open to using SSIS to achieve this?

Comment: @AlexVacar I'm not sure, are those integrated services included with SQL Server Management Studio 2008? If yes, then sure.

Comment: @omar K yes, it is part of the SQL Server installation media. Once installed, build a SSIS Package to export the data, and schedule it to occur daily via SQL Server Agent.

Comment: @AlexVacar Is there any other way without using SSIS Package?

Comment: @omarK - you can use BCP - [read about it here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/creating-csv-files-using-bcp-and-stored-procedures/).

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about bulk export which well documented in MSDN - [Importing and Exporting Bulk Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175937%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)